# How to get friends wall information through FBGraph or FBConnect?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, fbconnect

I am Using FBGraph API of Facebook for iPhone, here i get friend list, my profile, my feeds and other values but how can I get My Friends Wall Data through this API.

My Question is that How can i Get My Friends wall information though this API for iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/user/feed i think this is the graph path for getting feed info.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but what can i pass in feed.

Currently it will show

{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: user"
   }
}

Comment: Put the users id in place of users.

Comment: I use this url in this url 623405046 is my friend id. graph.facebook.com/623405046/feed. But I get Data Array Empty from this, how can i check read_stream Permission. Can any one suggest me.

Comment: you need to pass access token along with the url. https://graph.facebook.com/623405046/feed?access_token=urtoken

Comment: Thanks xCode, 

I get friends wall data by access token by this.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation covers this:

See the "feed" section on [this page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) for details.

e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/123456/feed
where 123456 is the user id

Note. You'll need to ensure you have the read_stream permission.

Comment: I use this url in this url 623405046 is my friend id. https://graph.facebook.com/623405046/feed. But I get Data Array Empty from this, how can i check read_stream Permission. Can any one suggest me.